# Is casting a mysqli result object to an array good practice?

Tags: php, mysqli

I was wondering, if I have some code such as:

```
$result = $db->query($sql); // dont worry, its escaped
$myData = (array)$result->fetch_assoc();
```

where

```
$result->fetch_assoc();
```

returns a mysqli result object.

Is casting it like this right away good practice? I would imagine this is an expensive call - is this true?

It sure makes things convenient to use immediately after I query for it, but I want to make sure I'm not doing something in bad form.

Thanks for any input,

Comment: Did you mean $result->fetch_assoc()?

Comment: Yes - thanks for catching that. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [mysqli documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) it returns an array anyway...

Comment: Thanks - I really can't figure out why I didn't catch that before :)

Answer (score 0):

If there is no more result - it will return NULL. In this case (array) null can have some sense.

Really it is better check special cases in separated place instead of type casting